# Remove the empty lines left by Jinja2 variable definitions

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

When writing template files using Jinja2 for Saltstack, I often define some variables at the beginning of the file. For example:

```
{% set ip = grains['ip4_interfaces']['eth1'][0] %}
{% set domain = pillar['company_domain'] %}
{% set version = pillar['site_version'] %}
{% set site_url = 'www.' + domain %}

[...]
```

Everything works fine but when opening the generated file, I get a block of empty lines where the jinja code was.

Am I doing something wrong ?
If not, is there any way to get rid of those empty lines when using templates ?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is [whitespace control](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#whitespace-control) in Jinja2.  You might want:

```
{%- set ip = grains['ip4_interfaces']['eth1'][0] -%}
{%- set domain = pillar['company_domain'] -%}
{%- set version = pillar['site_version'] -%}
{%- set site_url = 'www.' + domain -%}

[...]
```

As well, the salt [configuration file](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/configuration/examples.html) supports `jinja_trim_blocks` and `jinja_lstrip_blocks` (`jinja_env:trim_blocks`, `jinja_env:lstrip_blocks`, `jinja_sls_env:trim_blocks`, and `jinja_sls_env:lstrip_blocks` [as of 2018.3](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/pull/42930)).